# Evolution-EWS (Exchange) Address Book Isn't Syncing

Tags: evolution, exchange

I've installed evolution and evolution-ews. After setting up my exchange email account, I expected that the address books from the server would also sync. Under my Contacts, there are 6 address books. Two of them have the form of {some-UUID}, and the others are contacts, gal contacts, global address list, and recipient cache. However, they are all empty.

Is there a way to get the contact list from my server to sync with evolution? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem they didn't get synchronized